# Cache Types are invalidated

Tags: magento2, cache

Error: One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Configuration, Page Cache. Please go to Cache Management and refresh cache types. 
how can i resolve

Comment: go for `system > cache management > click on Flush magento cache`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to **system > cache management** > click on **Flush magento cache**

credits : **[Eirik](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/12188/eirik)**

Reasons for block cache invalidation is  from **updates to products, catalog price rule changes, and 3rd party extensions**. Also **running of cronjobs** can cause block caches to become invalidated as well.

Comment: In my website Update any prices on the backend it will not update on the front end. Is this because of this issue?